# Fullrankness of sum of time shifts

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, finite-groups, matrix-theory, circulant-matrices

I am working with finite Gabor frames and in this context a problem appeared which I am trying to solve for a couple of weeks now.

Given a $(p,k,1)$ cyclic difference set for $\mathbb{Z}_p$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ (lets call this subset $\mathcal{N} $ later I will sum over it), where $p$ is prime. Now we have given the cyclic shift matrix on $\mathbb{C}^p $ defined as $\textbf{T}(x_0 \; x_1 \; ... \; x_{p-1} )^T = (x_{p-1} \; x_0 \; x_1 \; ... \; x_{p-2} )^T $ where $(x_0 \; x_1 \; ... \; x_{p-1} )^T \in \mathbb{C}^p $. In matrix form $\textbf{T} $ is written as
\begin{align*}
\textbf{T}^1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & . & . & . & 0 \\
. &   & . &   &   &   & . \\
. &   &   & . &   &   & . \\
. &   &   &   & . &   & . \\
0 & . & . & . & . & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
A second matrix $\textbf{W} $ is a diagonal matrix defined as follows 
\begin{align*}
\textbf{W}^1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
\omega ^{n_1} &     &     &   &   &   &   \\ 
    & \omega ^{n_2} &     &   &   &   &   \\
    &     & \omega ^{n_3} &   &   &   &   \\
    &     &     & . &   &   &   \\
    &     &     &   & . &   &   \\
    &     &     &   &   & . &   \\
    &    &     &   &   &   & \omega ^{n_{p}}
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
where $\omega = \exp(i\frac{2 \pi}{p} )$ is the $p$th root of unity and $n_1 $ to $n_p $ are just some integers randomly choosen from the integers modulo $p$ with uniform distribution. In $n_1 $ to $n_p $ some numbers might appear more then once and some might not appear at all. For instance $\textbf{W} $ could also be the identity matrix.

What I would like to show is that the matrix 
\begin{align*}
\textbf{A} = \sum _{l\in\mathcal{N}} \textbf{T}^l \textbf{W}^l 
\end{align*}
has full rank.

I have done some simulations on MATLAB in small dimensions and every matrix I tested had full rank. Also if $n_1 = n_2 = ... = n_p $ then $\textbf{A} $ is a circulant matrix and has full rank. But I would like to show that $\textbf{A} $ has full rank independent from the values of $n_i $. I have tried a couple of attempts none of them led me anywhere. The most promising attempt was to show that $\textbf{I} + \textbf{T}^l \textbf{W}^l $ has full rank using the property that $ \left( \textbf{T}^l \textbf{W}^l \right) ^p  = \det \left( \textbf{W}^l \right) \textbf{I} $.

Comment: Given the last equality stated, it seems beneficial to work over $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]/(p)$. You have: $$A^p\equiv \sum (T^lW^l)^p\equiv\sum det(W^l)I.$$ p-th roots of unity have only one linear relation. If you don't fall on it, this proves $A$ has full rank over the cyclotomic ring, and hence also over complex numbers.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. There are some points I didn't fully understand since I am not familiar in Galois theory nor in number theory. I have an engineering background. If $\mathbf{A} $ has full rank over $\mathbb{Z}[\omega ] / (p) $ why does it imply that $\mathbf{A} $ has full rank over the complex numbers? Can you recommend me some literature/references so I can get some insights? Also by "cyclotomic ring" do you mean the extension of integers to the p-th roots of unity or the extension of rationals?

Comment: This all comes down to the determinant being non-zero, which is equivalent to full rank. Since all the entries of the matrix are in the ring of cyclotomic integers $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$, so is the determinant. Then we can go modulo $p$. A cyclotomic integer that is not zero modulo $p$ must itself be nonzero. Hence, if the reduction is of full rank, then the reduction of the determinant is nonzero, and then the determinant itself must be nonzero, and thus the original matrix has full rank no matter the ring (cyclotomic integers or complex). There are

Comment: There are multiple math.stackexchange questions on this question (full rank in quotient ring implies full rank). Milne's notes on algebraic number theory are classic by now, though they might involve more than you need.